# Changing signature of std::function in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std-function

C++17 allows us to not specify template parameters when they can be deduced from the constructor, e.g.:

```cpp
auto f = std::function([](A x){});
```

The type of `f` will be deduced as `std::function<void(A)>`.

Here, this means that calling `f(a)` (where `a` is an lvalue of type `A`) will produce a call to the copy-constructor of `A`, followed by a call to its move constructor. In comparison, calling the lambda directly would only produce a copy, not a move.

We can eliminate the move by forcing the use of a const reference, as follows:

```cpp
auto f = std::function<void(const A&)>([](A x){});
```

Now assume that I have this function:

```cpp
template<typename F>
auto make_function(F&& f) {
    return std::function(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

How can I make it do what I just did above, that is, add `const &` to any parameter that is passed by value?

Comment: What if `f` accepts an argument by rvalue? E.g., `f` would be `[](std::unique_ptr&& ptr) {}`?

Comment: You replace copy+move with a single copy, but an rvalue is passed, you instead replace move+move with a copy. The latter is probably undesirable. If this was so simple, `std::function` would do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had an epiphany right after posting my question. Here is the solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct add_reference;

template<typename T>
struct add_reference<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_reference<T>::value>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct add_reference<T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value>> {
    using type = const T&;
};

template<typename T>
using add_ref_t = typename add_reference<T>::type;

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename F, typename R, typename ... P>
auto make_function_from_model(F&& fun, const std::function<R(P...)>&) {
    return std::function<R(add_ref_t<P>...)>{std::forward<F>(fun)};
}

template<typename F>
auto make_function(F&& fun) {
    using fun_type = decltype(std::function{fun});
    return make_function_from_model(std::forward<F>(fun), fun_type{});
}

int main(){
    A a{};
    auto f = make_function([](A a){});
    f(a);
}
```

Comment: There already is [`std::add_lvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) and [`std::add_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_cv) :>

Comment: Again, this always forces a copy and never allows a move.

Comment: Well the copy is inevitable here, and actually expected (there is a copy when using the lambda). `std::add_lvalue_reference` doesn't work if some of the parameters of the lambda are rvalue references. My `add_reference` is a more generic way of keeping whatever type of reference already exists, and add it if there is none.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think you're right that it forces a copy even if I call `f(std::move(a))`, so there is still some work to do.

Comment: @sunmat I don't think you can do anything. With a custom `function` class - maybe, but not with `std::function`.